# Extract one particular channel from a png using scikit-image

Tags: scikit-image

I'm evaluating scikit-image and looking for a way to read only green channel from my images.
The images are stored as RGBA having only green channel with values.

Is there something similar to CvSplit as found in OpenCV?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Images are stored as `MxNxd` arrays where, in your case, `d == 4`.  So, use standard NumPy slicing to get hold of green:

```
green = image[..., 1]
```

Comment: Is this different than green=image[:,:,1]?

Comment: No, that's exactly the same.  The ellipsis fills in all missing dimensions.